# How to render into Surface using OpenGL ES, without GLSurfaceRenderer

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk, rendering

I need to draw a decoded video frame into an `android.view.Surface` object, in Android native C++ code.

I understand that the common way to do this is to implement `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` interface and call the native method from `onDrawFrame()`. But I cannot use that, I need to pass the Surface object to the native method and work on it from there.

I'm planning on using OpenGL ES APIs to do all the rendering job, because it's cross-platform. But I have no idea where does the Surface object comes in.

I've seen several examples where `ANativeWindow_fromSurface()` is used. I guess I could go that way it if I was not compelled to use OpenGL.

So where do I "set" my Surface object inside native code, so I am good-to-go to rendering my scene frames?

**EDIT:** Ok, I guess I just was not aware of [EGL standard](http://www.khronos.org/egl), which seems to be what I need in the presented case.

However, I am still looking for a way to "map" or "convert" a `android.view.Surface` object into whatever structure handled by EGL context, which I assume to be `EGLNativeWindowType`, without needing to access any Android-specific APIs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Java sources, you pass the Surface as an argument to `eglCreateWindowSurface()`, which returns an EGLSurface.  You then pass this to `eglMakeCurrent()` to establish it as the destination for your rendering.  Unfortunately I'm not sure what the NDK equivalents are, but native `eglCreateWindowSurface` should take an `ANativeWindow` reference as its 3rd argument.

Comment: Thank you fadden. However, I assume that I can only obtain the `ANativeWindow` reference by calling `ANativeWindow_fromSurface()`, which is Android-specific. I guess there's no other way for that.

Comment: OpenGL doesn't know anything about Windows or X11 or Android, so you need a layer between it and the underlying window/compositing system.  For Windows it's WGL, on Android it's EGL.  EGL tries to be OS-agnostic, so you need to pass a window-system-specific handle into the surface creation method.  On Android that's an ANativeWindow.  "Surface" is an ANativeWindow that can do things like send buffers of graphics data to the compositor.